# Different format in pandas date column - data type of column vs. row

Tags: python, regex, pandas, date, types

I have a pd DataFrame column with date values that are in different Format. Examples are 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss' and 'DD.MM.YYYY' or even 'DD.MM.' I'd like to convert them all to one Format (e.g., 'YYYY-MM-DD') and have (among many things) tried

```
df[~df.date.str.contains('(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})')]
```

to find rows where the date is not written as 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'. However, this does not work.

I therefore checked the type of the column

```
df['date'].dtype   #prints dtype('O')
```

Then I checked

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(type(row['date']))
```

and received a mixture of prints such as class 'datetime.datetime' and class 'str'

I am confused. Why do I not always get 'str' when the column is an 'object' datatype? And does someone by any Chance know how to make the regex work?

Comment: ***I'd like to convert them all to one Format*** - Which one?

Comment: one way would to be convert them to datetime object and you can decide the format i guess...

Comment: @PedroLobito preferrably YYYY-MM-DD. I've edited my post

Comment: Well, what year do you want to assign to the DD.MM dates? That's the only format it cant automatically parse, so if you just modify those strings and add a year, one call to `pd.to_datetime` will convert everything

Comment: @Alollz exactly what I was thinking! But I couldn't filter the dataframe to such rows. Any advice? Thought about checking for the length of the string but couldn't get my code to run. I have the year in another column which I could add to the string

Comment: If you are *certain* the format is always DD.MM you could do `df.loc[df.date.str.len() == 5, 'date'] += '.2017'`, for instance. If perhaps it could be D.M then maybe make it `< 5`.

Comment: Thanks @ALollz, your answer and Ashutosh Chapagain's saved me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def findIndex(x):
    try:
        pd.to_datetime(x).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
        return
    except:
        return True


df.date.apply(lambda x: findIndex(x))
```

Now you can get all the index with **weird** formats. Hope this helps.

Comment: I actually tried this before but only got the error "ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', '01.01.')" because some years have missing years as mentioned in the post. That's why I wanted to filter the dataframe to those with weird formats and add the missing years 'by hand'

Comment: Try `df.date.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')[0])` instead

Comment: You can use your function instead of lambda func. with try/catch blocks and try several datetime formats.